# How to capture SSIS source & destination error records into one file

Tags: ssis, etl

My goal is to write error records from both source and destination into one file.
Currently, I'm encountering

> Warning: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

PS: As I explore this feature, I can write these error records into two separate files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining two flat file destinations, define just one and union the error outputs to it.

Comment: my source flat file error(s) are data is not in correct format for ex: non-UTF .. so I'm trying to write to a file via "data conversion" step.. then the destination is a sqlServer table .. there are some errors record due to inconsistencies -- that I would like to write same error output file.. when I try to, as I mention i'm encountering ".,. file because it is being used by another process." error .. how can I resolve that issue?

Comment: i explored what you suggested with "union all" and it worked.  Thank you